# Trying to create a Java script function that when button is pushed an image would appear

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, onclick

Im trying to create an interactive story in which one can chose between two options, once pushing yes or no, an image would appear with a story line. I am tryig to create a function that would make the image appear when one of the buttons are pushed. I dont know where i have gone wrong. Thank you for your help :).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>interactive dragon story</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
        #stage1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 300px;
    display: inline; 
        }

    .yes {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30%;
        top: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 30px;
        background-color: green;
        }
     .no {
        position: absolute;
        left: 45%;
        top: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 30px;
        background-color: greenyellow;

        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var photo;
        var x;

        function choice1()
        {
        if (x == 1)
        {
        document.getElementById(photo).src = "images/dragon1.jpg" ;
        }

        else (x == 0)
        { 
        document.write = "would you like to listen to some music?";          
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id="stage1">Would you like to read a story?</h1>

    <input type="button" value="Yes" class="yes" onclick=choice1(1);" />
    <input type="button" value="No" class="no" onclick="choice1(0);" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `else (x == 0)` is not correct. Its either just `else` or `else if (x == 0)`

Comment: put image tag  <img src = "" id = "image"/>

Comment: You haven't declared the argument in function choice1()

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put `x` as parameter for your `choice1` function and you should use `else if (x == 0)` instead of `else (x == 0)`:

```
function choice1(x){
  if (x == 1){
    document.getElementById(photo).src = "images/dragon1.jpg" ;
  }else if (x == 0){ 
    document.write = "would you like to listen to some music?";          
  }
}
```

You also need to actually include img tag in your html

```
<img id="photo" src="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to do two things :

1) create an `img` tag with `src=""`

2) The function declaration and definition should match

**Html**

```
<input type="button" value="Yes" class="yes" onclick=choice1(1);" />
    <input type="button" value="No" class="no" onclick="choice1(0);" />
     <img src = "" id = "image"/>
```

**JS**

```
function choice1(x)
{
if(x==1)
{
     document.getElementById("image").src = "images/dragon1.jpg" ;
    }
else
{
document.getElementById("image").src = "would you like to listen to some music?" ;
}

}
```